# How can I add borders to merged cells Apache poi?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

`I have merged cells
here's what they look like, there are 22 of them also I have 2 css cs styles, Now you need to add borders to the merged cells, I tried to add borders, but then the text style is updated

```
cellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(1, 1, 4, 8);

public CellStyle mergedStyle(CellStyle textStyle, Sheet sheet,Workbook workbook){ CellStyle styleBorder = workbook.createCellStyle(); styleBorder.cloneStyleFrom(textStyle); styleBorder.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM); styleBorder.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM); styleBorder.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM); styleBorder.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

//there are 13 here because 13 columns is correct    
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= 13; rowIndex++) {
        Row row1 = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
        if (row1 == null) {
            row1 = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);  
        }
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex <= 13; columnIndex++) {
            Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(columnIndex); 
            if (cell1 == null) {
                cell1 = row1.createCell(columnIndex);       
            }
            cell1.setCellStyle(styleBorder);    
        }
    }
    return styleBorder;    }
CellStyle cellStyleCss = mergedStyle(css, sheet, workbook); CellStyle cellStyleCs = mergedStyle(cs, sheet, workbook);
```

with this usage, only some are displayed with borders`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a CSS framework or boilerplate to simplify your code and make it more consistent.

You could use CSS grid or flexbox to achieve this layout. Both methods allow you to create rows and columns of elements and control their spacing and alignment. There are many resources available online that can help you learn how to use these techniques effectively.

Edit: also in your loop, instead of calling mergedStyle just assign the borderStyle to the cells, with this all cells will have the same border style applied.